# Alert when a textbox is empty and prevent submit button from submitting

Tags: php, textbox, alert

Ok so I've been working on some little HTML and PHP and I want a specific event to actually happen after clicking the submit button given a textbox is left empty. I've looked for tons of javascript codes and all of them didn't work (or probably I have not worked enough to deal with them and make them work) and I don't even know if javascript would only be the solution. I'm really not that good at javascript and I don't know if there are some other ways to deal with this. I would want that the user would be alerted after clicking the submit button if the user leaves a textbox empty, and prevent the button from submitting and entering the action from form so that the user can enter their inputs before entering to the php code. I've read that the two can't actually go together, php and javascript with this kind of alert and prevention and all, and if ever it is, would there be other ways to deal with this?

Comment: It's called `form validation` where the textarea is a **required** element. If you GOOGLE these terms together, you should be able to find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript could help you with this,
most likely you would like something like this for the HTML part:

```
<form onSubmit="return validate(this);" ...>
     <input type="text" id="usefulId"></input>
     <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

For the javascript, everything depends on what you exactly want to achieve, however I use something like this:

```
function validate(theForm)
{
    var valid = true
    var textbox = document.getElementById("usefulId");

    if (textbox.value) {
         textbox.setAttribute("class", "valid");
    } else {
         textbox.setAttribute("class", "invalid");
         valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

If you then add some css to color the textbox red or something like that the user should be informed.
Some good practices would of course be to move the real validation to another function which is being called, so you can reuse it. If you somehow want to give some some information about why it is wrong, you can off course write some code to fill in a label, ...

The HTML5 also has some thing that could help you: The attribute required (here written to comply to xhtml)

```
<form onSubmit="return validate(this);" ...>
     <input type="text" id="usefulId" required="required"></input>
     <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

However, this only works on the browsers supporting html5 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation) so no support for IE6-9 if I found the right page and a few other browser (versions).
Even though this means that you could not rely on it to fix your issue, it gives some nice effects generate by the browser.